# Simple class issue in java

Tags: java, class

Can someone please tell me whats wrong here????

```
package javaapplication2;

public class JavaApplication2{

        int number;

    public int JavaApplication2(int number){
        this.number = number;
        return number;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){       
    JavaApplication2 object = new JavaApplication2(2); // This line generates error
    }

}
```

im getting the error:

Constructor JavaApplication2 in class JavaApplication2 cannot be applied to given types??????????

Comment: syntax errors are off topic here.

Comment: Read up how to do a Java constructor. A constructor in Java cannot have a return type. Take away `int` from `public int JavaApplication2`

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax for the constructor is incorrect. A constructor doesn't have a return type. So what you defined was a regular method. Then when you tried to construct an instance of an object the only constructor the compiler could find is the default constructor which takes no arguments.

Here's a possible fix:

```
package javaapplication2;

public class JavaApplication2{

    int number;

    public JavaApplication2(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }



    public static void main (String[] args){       
        JavaApplication2 object = new JavaApplication2(2); 
    }

}
```

Or perhaps you really meant JavaApplication2 to be a method. Then your only option is to call the default constructor.

```
package javaapplication2;

public class JavaApplication2{

        int number;

    public int JavaApplication2(int number){
        this.number = number;
        return number;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){       
        JavaApplication2 object = new JavaApplication2(); 
    }

}
```

However, this would be very strange. At the very least you'd want to rename your method.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is not a normal method, and does not return anything. Try this:

```
public JavaApplication2(int number){
    this.number = number;
}
```